# How can I get the sheet name to populate in a cell using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Noob here. I make hundreds of seemingly identical spreadsheets that get shared with various locations. In the past I pulled the title of the sheet into a cell at the top to help keep things organized however now the same script isn't working in a new sheet or when I make a copy of an old sheet.

In the old version of Apps Script I was using:

function onOpen(e){e.source.getRange('Master!A1').setValue(e.source.getName());}

However now I'm getting an error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
onOpen  @ Code.gs:1

The tab name matches, there's nothing in that cell, there's an ImportRange function in the cell below but that has not impacted things in the past. My old sheets with that script still work however when I make a copy of the sheet, the script copies over and seems to work for a second but then stops working. Any help to get the Sheet Title to populate in cell A1 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you're running the onOpen function from the script editor. The sheet is already opened when you run it, that's why you get that message. Your code works when you actually open the sheet ;)

Comment: This script also works when supplying the event object to populate the e parameter. Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as an installable script

```
function onMyOpen(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  e.source.getRange('Sheet0!A1').setValue(e.source.getName());
}
```

Comment: It did not work for me, and returns a similar error code:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
onMyOpen @ Code.gs:3

Comment: You cannot run the onOpen without supplying the event object to populate the e parameter.  Try closing the spreadsheet and the opening it again after saving the script